# ko.toJSON did not convert JS object into JSON string

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js

inside my view model i have the following JS object which contains the observable values

```
var COAData = {
                ACCOUNT_CODE: self.ACCOUNT_CODE,
                ACCOUNT_NAME: self.ACCOUNT_NAME,
                ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION: self.ACCOUNT_DESCRIPTION,
                OPENING_BALANCE: self.OPENING_BALANCE,
                ACCOUNT_DATE: self.ACCOUNT_DATE,
                MAIN_ACCOUNT: self.MAIN_ACCOUNT,
                SUB_ACCOUNT: self.SUB_ACCOUNT,
                CONTROLL_ACCOUNT: self.CONTROLL_ACCOUNT,
                SUBSIDERY_ACCOUNT: self.SUBSIDERY_ACCOUNT,
                ACCOUNT_TYPE: self.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
                VOUCHING_ACCOUNT: self.VOUCHING_ACCOUNT
            };
```

and i am using following ajax function to send the above JS object as JSON string to my controller in MVC, to save the data into the database.

```
self.submitCOA = function () {                           
                $.ajax(                
                    {
                        type: "post",
                        url: "/ChartOfAccounts/Create",                        
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: ko.toJSON(COAData),
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert("New Accoungt with Account #" + self.ACCOUNT_CODE(data.ACCOUNT_CODE) + "added successfully");
                            //GetChartOfAccounts();
                        },//success function end
                        error: function (error) {
                            alert(error.status + "<!----!>" + error.statusText);
                        }//error function end
                    }
                    );//ajax function end
            };
```

while debugging, i came to know that ko.toJSON did not convert the JS object (COAData) into JSON string. Instead an empty string is passed to the contrller

any help?

Comment: maybe ko.toJSON(new COAData)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ko.toJS` instead of `ko.toJSON`, also if `self.ACCOUNT_CODE` is observable you should write `self.ACCOUNT_CODE()` and etc. (with `()`).